# Error while compiling : "invalid operands to binary / (have ‘short int *’ and ‘int’)"

Tags: c, syntax-error

```
short int cipher[50],len;
while(cipher != 0)
{  
    cipher=cipher/10;
    ++len;
}
```

Need to count number of digits provided by user.

```
 error: invalid operands to binary / (have ‘short int *’ and ‘int’)
           cipher=cipher/10;
```

Comment: cipher is an array. you need to index it!

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you need to provide more code. You are probably facing an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gsamaras noted, you defined `cipher` as an array of 50 `short int`s. Presumably you want only one number, so you'd define it e. g. as `long long cipher;` (C is not COBOL or something where one has to specify the number of digits). And don't forget to initialize `len`.